# Is a set sandwiched between two measurable sets whose difference is zero set measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

More specifically, if there is a $F_\sigma$ set and a $G_\delta$ set such that $m(G/\ F)=0$. If there is a set $E$ sandwiched between them, namely, $F\subset E \subset G$, Can we say $E$ is measurable? Because I believe in Pugh's real mathematical analysis on the regularity of measurable set, it just says that every measurable set can be sandwiched between a $F_\sigma$ set and a $G_\delta$ set, but it does not say that a set being sandwiched is necessarily a measurable set. So does it mean it is false in general?

Comment: The answer is yes; this is true.

Comment: Every subset of a nullset is a nullset, and $E=F\cup(E\setminus F)$, so $E$ is measurable.

Answer (score 0):

This is true.  An equivalent statement is that "Lebesgue outer measure" and "Lebesgue inner measure" agree with the measure of a set for any measurable set.